# Interpretation of Elastic Net Model

Tags: r, regression

I have a code for an elastic net model which is predicting the best lambda to use. With this, it provides coefficients for those values. I wanted to see how accurate those coefficients are that it generated, but I'm not sure how to compute accuracy for them. Any thoughts?

Here's the code for the elastic net and dataset:

```
set.seed(12)
n <- 200
coefs <- rep(c(2, -1, 0), each=30)
epsilon <- rnorm(n, 0, 10)
x <- matrix(nrow=n, ncol=90)
for(i in 1:90){
  x[, i] <- rnorm(200, 0, 1)
}
y <- rep(NA, n)
for(i in 1:n){
  y[i] = sum(x[i,]*coefs) + epsilon[i]
}
data <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)

set.seed(12)
dim(data)
head(data)
numericvars <- c(1:90)
sample <- data[1:100,]     #I only wanted the first 100 data observations for this.
x <- as.matrix(sample[,numericvars])
y <- sample$y
newdata <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)

lambdalevels <- 10^seq(7,-2,length=100)

library(glmnet)
ridge.mod=glmnet(x,y,alpha=0,lambda=lambdalevels)
coef(ridge.mod)[,100]
plot(ridge.mod,xvar="lambda")

middle.mod=glmnet(x,y,alpha=0.5,lambda=lambdalevels)
plot(middle.mod,xvar="lambda")

lasso.mod=glmnet(x,y,alpha=1,lambda=lambdalevels)
plot(lasso.mod,xvar="lambda")

set.seed(12)
cv.lasso.mod=cv.glmnet(x,y,alpha=1,lambda=lambdalevels)
plot(cv.lasso.mod)

bestlambda <- cv.lasso.mod$lambda.min
coefs <- predict(lasso.mod, type="coefficients",s=bestlambda)
```

Here are the coefficients I get:

```
91 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

(Intercept) -0.167564375    
x.1          1.631117431
x.2          .          
x.3          .          
x.4          .          
x.5          0.681934674
x.6          0.309141489
x.7          1.099379025
x.8          1.087376314
x.9          0.302149946
x.10         0.015998582
x.11         0.288141307
x.12         1.256299269
x.13         1.056323266
x.14         1.535587611
x.15         1.137616700
x.16         0.225478965
x.17         0.505928229
x.18         .          
x.19         1.190590924
x.20         2.058489311
x.21         .          
x.22         1.688636268
x.23         2.061530905
x.24         0.618335400
x.25         .          
x.26         .          
x.27         0.463405536
x.28         0.028798839
x.29         .          
x.30         1.085691534
x.31        -0.665697847
x.32        -1.452097498
x.33         .          
x.34         .          
x.35         .          
x.36         .          
x.37         .          
x.38         .          
x.39         .          
x.40        -0.009110380
x.41         .          
x.42         0.199324433
x.43         0.694738515
x.44         .          
x.45        -1.496049876
x.46         .          
x.47         .          
x.48        -2.691493897
x.49         .          
x.50        -2.107344734
x.51         0.573354698
x.52        -0.098378699
x.53        -0.003158034
x.54        -1.055646010
x.55        -0.648864691
x.56        -0.185288075
x.57         .          
x.58        -0.003201519
x.59         .          
x.60        -0.330444362
x.61         .          
x.62         .          
x.63         .          
x.64         .          
x.65         .          
x.66         .          
x.67         0.010839710
x.68         .          
x.69         .          
x.70         .          
x.71        -1.512228491
x.72         .          
x.73         0.281044294
x.74         .          
x.75         .          
x.76         .          
x.77        -0.086147448
x.78         .          
x.79         .          
x.80        -0.126396868
x.81         .          
x.82        -1.470280928
x.83         .          
x.84         .          
x.85         .          
x.86         0.005316165
x.87         0.492648763
x.88        -0.730390919
x.89         .          
x.90         0.672031175
```

Any suggestions and thoughts and help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Interpreting results for a statistical model or testing for accuracy aren't really programming questions. If you have questions about fitting statistical models, you should be asking over at [stats.se]

Comment: I second @MrFlick. For a reference see http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/B67.2%20(2005)%20301-320%20Zou%20&%20Hastie.pdf. Their book is also very useful

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether the model’s predictions are accurate, or are you trying to determine whether the coefficients are an accurate reflection of real-world processes? Penalized coefficients shouldn’t be used for hypothesis testing (e.g. does age make someone more likely to have the outcome) because they are biased towards zero

Answer (score 1):

Elastic net unfortunately doesn't produce standard errors for coefficients.  It's actually pretty difficult to get standard errors when the problem isn't well-suited for OLS / GLM, for example when there are many predictor variables and/or predictors have multicollinearity.

One option is to perform bootstrapping + elastic net to produce distributions of coefficients which can be used as estimates for standard errors.  This has been a useful tool for me in practice, although I'm sure there are legitimate concerns from a theoretical perspective about bootstrapping in combination with a method that performs variable selection.

Another option is a gaussian process model or Bayesian model as alternatives to elastic net.  Either one should (I believe!) have ability to control overfitting and produce standard errors, although going this route will require more model specification and deliberate decisions.

On a separate note, I recommend preparing a table of standardized coefficients from elastic net sorted by decreasing magnitude.  This is a great and simple way to rank the importance and display the directionality of the predictor variable effects.

Answer (score 0):

You have estimated 91 coefficients (don't forget the intercept).

You know the values of those by looking at `coefs`, and then your intercept is zero.

Computer the distance between those two $91$-dimensional vectors using any number of methods: absolute distance ($L1$ norm), Euclidean distance ($L2$ norm), maximum distance ($L_{\infty}$ norm), etc.

If you have a method that you would use to evaluate coefficient accuracy for coefficients estimated by the usual OLS estimation, I would use that. Elastic net is, in some sense, just another way to estimate the coefficients in a linear model, no different from choosing to estimate variance using $\frac{\sum\big(X_i - \bar X\big)^2}{n}$ vs $\frac{\sum\big(X_i - \bar X\big)^2}{n - 1}$.